# NSViewAnimation flickers for NSWindow with kCGDesktopWindowLevel

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, nsviewanimation

I have an `NSWindow` set to `kCGDesktopWindowLevel` so it sits on the desktop behind the desktop icons (like a wallpaper).

I'm trying to cross-fade two views inside that window using an `NSViewAnimation`.

The problem is that the animation flickers a lot. I tracked it down to the window level.

```
self.window.level = kCGDesktopWindowLevel;
```

If I use the default window level the animation runs smoothly just as expected.

Any suggestions what could be the reason? Is there anything different how windows are drawn at that level?

**Edit:**

Could this be a RunLoop issue? Background windows don't receive user input. However, my app also has another normal window that can receive input.

Comment: YES, someone has the same issue :), well... sort of, I have a window set to kCGDesktopWindowLevel and I have website running it that has a lot of animations, and they just flicker like mad as well, I have no clue why, if I slow down the animation it gets less flickery but I've not found a solution :(

Comment: @Lenny Glad to hear that I'm not alone with this problem! Could this be related to RunLoops? The animations run in the current run loop, although I tried "background thread" as option without success.

Comment: I'd love to help, but unfortunately my objective-c and cocoa knowledge is close to 0 :( I was just trying to get a program to display a website as a wallpaper, as I am on mac there wasn't a decent software I could find so i made my own, and it works, but any animations in the website cause the whole thing to flicker :(, I tried another program which I found online, later, and it has the same issue, so this may be a bug... I'm clueless